# png image in response in custom python web-server

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I am writing a simple webserver in python and have been successful in doing so. I am able to render html pages in javascript files but unable to render images.

Some of the relevant code,

```
def createResponse(self, data):#, last_modified=0):
        # print data
        response_code = data[0]
        mimetype  = data[1][1]
        data = data[1][0]               # (200, (data, mimetype))

        res = "HTTP/1.0 " + self.config['STATUS_STRING'][str(response_code)] + "\r\n"
        res += "Content-Type: " + mimetype + "\r\n"
        res += "Date: " + strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT", gmtime()) + "\r\n"
        # if last_modified:
        #     res += "Last Modified: " + last_modified + "\r\n"
        res += 'Server: ' + self.config['SERVER_NAME'] + "\r\n"
        res += 'Connection: close' + '\r\n'  # signal that the conection wil be closed after complting the request
        res += "\r\n"
        res += data

        return res.encode("utf8")

def _handleGET(self, path):
    # some stuff, then
    # File exists and read permission, so give file
    try:
        fp = open(filepath, "rb")
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EACCES:
            return (500, self._readFile(self.config['ERROR_DIR'] + '/' + str(500) + ".html"));
        # Not a permission error.
        raise
    else:
        with fp:
            return (200, (fp.read().decode("utf8"), mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)[0])) # return (200,(data,mimetype))
```

I create a socket to the client, and the return the response using this,

```
clientSocket.sendall(self.createResponse(self._handleGET(data)))
```

I encode the whole response, which is a string, in utf8. This works for html pages and js files, and css files but not for images. (png, gif etc). I tried settings the headers and encoding the response of images in base64 binary etc, but i am not able to achieve it.

- Any suggestions on how to do it?
- Is this even possible, because now i think its not possible to render images using this method, as the headers would be in `utf8` while the content of images would be in other encoding. So they can't be concatenated. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Don't try to write a http-server by yourself. Use a framework like flask or bottle.

Comment: Obviously the pre-made servers are going to be much better, but regardless it's a good learning experience to write a basic one on your own to understand what's going on behind the scenes

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya: I'm curious. Why are you passing `self` as an argument to `_handleGET`? Instance methods are already passed `self`, so it should suffice to do `self._handleGET(data)` instead.

Comment: @Daniel yes, you are correct. But i want to learn and understand how things work, and moreover it would be fun. Also, my main aim is to understand sockets and how different applications use them.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan sorry, it was a typo. Thanks for pointing out. Corrected !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header of http is not encoded, and should be pure ASCII. The content part is any binary data. For text, the encoding may be specified in the `Content-Type`.
Therefore `createResponse` has to handle text and binary data seperately, maybe with explicit encoding parameter:

```
def create_response(self, content, response_code=200, mimetype='text/html', encoding='UTF-8', additional_params=None):
    header_params = {
        'Content-Type', '%s; charset=%s' %(mimetype, encoding) if encoding else mimetype,
        'Date': strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT", gmtime()),
        'Server': self.config['SERVER_NAME'],
        'Connection': 'close',
    }
    if additional_params:
        header_params.update(additional_params)

    if encoding:
        content = content.encode(encoding)

    header = "HTTP/1.0 %s\r\n%s\r\n" % (
        self.config['STATUS_STRING'][str(response_code)],
        ''.join('%s: %s\r\n' % kv for kv in header_params.iteritems())
    )
    return header.encode('utf8') + content
```

using with:

```
    with fp:
        return self.create_response(fp.read(), mime_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)[0], encoding=None)
```

Comment: but, what should be the content returned when i want to render a png image? should it be binary?

Comment: I am trying what you suggested with a mp3 file, but it does not work.
i am just reading the mp3 data using `data = fp.read()` by opening the file in binary format. And then returning  the response as `header + data` but it gives the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
`

Comment: So you have somewhere utf8-strings. Code corrected.

Comment: My code works fine is  remove the lines `content = content.encode(encoding)`. I receive the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)` when i do so. Since the content is binary, so i removed the line from your code. Correct if i have missed something.